# Cant plot and compare two plots?

Tags: plotting

I am trying to compare two functions, this function;

```
Funcdeep[Dx] := Hx /. FindRoot[{DR[Dx], fluxx[Dx]}, {{kx, 0.1}, {Hx, 0.1}}]
DeepW = Plot[Funcdeep[Dx], {Dx, D0, d}]
```

and this one;

```
DeepW2 = Plot[Hp[D2n], {D2n, D0, d2}, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

Using this:

```
Show[SurfZ, DeepW2, DeepW, PlotRange -> {{0, 105.5}, {0, 8}},
```

AxesLabel -> {"Depth [m]", "Wave height [m]"}]

I am getting the error:

[image: Error]

I managed to get it work earlier, but cant for the life of me figure it out now.

Comment: It's hard to answer this without the full code, try to provide a minimal working example.

Comment: What is `SurfZ` ?

Comment: The definition for `Funcdeep` needs a pattern on the LHS: `Funcdeep[Dx_] := RHS`